# Explicitly call Xindy for glossaries package to create list of symbols

Tags: glossaries, xindy

Using the glossaries package I've added a user defined glossary:

```
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}
```

I've manually build the list of symbols using xindy but I just cannot find the exact command I used (and of course long forgotten since then). The glossary is defined in a file aux/symbols.tex which is included in the main file main.tex. The layout is as follows:

main.tex
aux/symbols.tex

I guess I triggered xindy from within the directory of main.tex, but besides I cannot remember any more.

```
xindy -I xindy ???
```

Can someone please tell me how to correctly invoke xindy to create the list of symbols? Thanks.

//Edit:

I've included \makeindex in main.tex and also call make makeindex when building the document. My build process is as follows:

```
latex $(DOCUMENT)
latex $(DOCUMENT)
makeindex $(DOCUMENT).idx
makeglossaries $(DOCUMENT)
bibtex $(DOCUMENT)
latex $(DOCUMENT)
latex $(DOCUMENT)
dvipdf $(DOCUMENT).dvi
```

where $(DOCUMENT) is "main". I've tried to fix this but ended up calling xindy directly because it was faster (once I still remembered the correct call).

// Edit2:

makeglossaries version 2.12 (2014-01-20

Xindy nor makeglossaries produce any errors, but the (only used) glossary which should be generated by `\printglossary[type=symbols]` does not exist in the document.

Only the sbl file is created.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually the utility `makeglossaries` is used for this, which automatically launches MakeIndex or Xindy with the correct parameters.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you. For some reason this doesn't work for me. I've updated my question accordingly. But calling xindy directly is fine - I just don't want to spend any more time on this than necessary. It's been too much time already to set everything up.

Comment: In what way did `makeglossaries` not work? (Did it produce any error messages? Did it create the other glossaries used in the document, but just not the symbols one? Was the `.slg` file created?) What version of `makeglossaries` do you have?

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The current version of `makeglossaries` is 2.15. Are any messages printed to the console when you run `makeglossaries`? (Try running `makeglossaries` explicitly from the command prompt.) Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) this is just guesswork, but here are some checks: make sure `\newglossary` is used before `\makeglossaries`; if `\newglossary` is in a different file from the main `.tex` file, have you input it using `\input` rather than `\include`?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question, here is the correct call for xindy when creating a new glossary with the following entry:

```
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}
```

where

- *slg* is the extension of the log file generated by xindy
- *sym* is the input file for latex generated by xindy
- *sbl* is the output file generated by latex and processed by xindy

Calling xindy as follows generates the

```
xindy -L english -I xindy -M main -t main.slg -o main.sym main.sbl
```

main.sym to be processed by latex. Here, *main* is the name of the latex file including the \begin{document}.